# Rails 3.1.1 ActiveRecord table_name= doesn't work

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I was stuck for quite a while on this:

```
class Something< ActiveRecord::Base
  table_name= "different_name"
end
```

and it didn't work, saying table 'Something' does not exist (which is true), until I changed that doomed line to

```
  set_table_name "different_name"
```

This would be OK, except that [Rails Guide](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-table_name) claims that set_table_name is 'Also aliased as: table_name='.

Now, I am new to rails, but what does that 'also aliased' mean? Or is this just a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to do `self.table_name = "different_name"` to use that form. This is a ruby thing: it is assigning a local variable `table_name` rather than actually calling the method.